# Cannot launch gluon app on iPad simulator

Tags: ios, gluon-mobile

I created a basic gluon app for iOS and when I try to launch it (right-click on project > Tasks > launch > IPadSimulator) I get the output below. I have a macbook pro running Mac OS X Sierra, Xcode 8.3.3, Netbeans 8.2 with Gluon plugin 2.5.0.

```
Executing: gradle :launchIPadSimulator

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:createDefaultIOSLauncher
:compileIosJava UP-TO-DATE
:processIosResources UP-TO-DATE
:iosClasses UP-TO-DATE
:iosExtractNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
:launchIPadSimulator
Root pattern javax.annotations.**.* matches no classes
Root pattern javax.inject.**.* matches no classes
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch i386)
2017-06-17 13:51:15.618 simlauncher[2058:23258] ERROR: dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/DTDeviceKitBase, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/DVTDeviceFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTDeviceFoundation
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/DTDeviceKitBase
  Reason: image not found

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 15.489 secs
```

The build is successful, but the simulator does not start. I am able to launch the simulator and run apps from Xcode however.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file or at least the jfxmobile plugin version of your project?

Comment: jfxmobile plugin version is 1.3.5
Here is a link to the build.gradle file: [gist](https://gist.github.com/emilh91/9e82ae4a8c1dfba9b4102c9299616ac5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce the issue, and it has already been reported elsewhere ([here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=26106) or [here](https://github.com/MobiDevelop/robovm/issues/129)).

As you can see [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin), the current version of the jfxmobile plugin (1.3.5) is using on iOS MobiDevelop 2.3.0.

After Apple released iOS 10.3, several issues have been reported: deploying to mobile was failing after installation was complete (verification failed at 90%), and now the issue with the simulator.

MobiDevelop 2.3.1 has been recently released with some fixes.

Using this version I've just verified that the issue with the Simulator is fixed as well. Anyway, I've just created an internal issue to notify this problem.

When the jfxmobile plugin gets updated with the new MobiDevelop version, the issue will be solved.

In the meantime, if you need it, you can fork the repository, modify it and build it yourself.

Comment: Thank you José. Would you happen to know when the next version of the jfxmobile plugin would be released?

Comment: The new version has just been released, fixing the issue.

Comment: Thanks José! I will check it out. If it works, I will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks José. It worked with version 1.3.6 of the javafxmobile plugin.